# How to handle UITabbarItem menu Items with Custom Buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I having an Application with different tabs(with different ViewControllers).
I have used **UITabbarController and hide the tabbar**, Initially 4 tabs are there. some times I need to show only 2 or 3 different tabs. How can I hide this with buttons(with tabBar selected index).

**4 tabs**

[image]

**3 other tabs**

[image]

**2 tabs**

[image]

Comment: Did you create the buttons in storyboard or code?

Comment: UItabbarController in storyBoard.

Comment: Well you can create an IBOutlet to your button and just say myButton.setHidden = NO;

Comment: Or you can create an NSMutableArray and remove the objects or add the objects as necessary

Comment: @soulshined:  not only for button I having UItabbarController with 7 tabs(each having different Viewcontrollers). at first shows only 4 tabs. when tap on this with some condition the tabbar shows 2 or 3 tabs(i.e., different viewcontroller).

Comment: so your saying each tab bar is in it's own view controller. So VC 1 has a tab bar with 3 tabs. And VC 2 has a tab bar with 2 tabs. When you click on VC 1 tab bar with 3 tabs at the 1st bar item it presents VC 2 with a tab bar with 2 tabs correct?

Comment: @soulshined: in some scenario only having a VC with 3 other new tabs. some times I need to show 2 existing tabs only (need to hide other tabs).

Comment: I understand, so since it's created in storyboard you can create IBOutlet to it and setHidden = YES; in your if statements. Then reverse it when necessary.

Comment: For which controller I need to set IBOutlet ?

Answer (score 0):

Vineesh,

This is an example to specific tab bar items. You can allocate this anywhere in your if statements to maintain flexibility.

```
NSMutableArray *tabbarItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.tabBarController viewControllers]];
[tabbarItems removeObjectAtIndex:/*Select your bar item[s] you wish to hide*/];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:tabbarItems];
```

Or you can create an IBOutlet to the bar item since your using storyboard and setHidden = YES; when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to store the instances of all the tabBarItem. The items property of UITabBar will give all the UITabbarItems currently it contains. Then you can add/remove the UITabBarItems into/ from  items array according to your needs.

```
NSMutableArray * tabBarItems = self.tabBar.items.mutableCopy ;
```

If you want to remove the facebook and twitter item add the below line

```
[tabBarItems removeObject:self.tabbarItemFacebook];
[tabBarItems removeObject:self.tabbarItemTwitter];

self.tabBar.items = tabBarItems ;
```

hope that it will help you :)